# In MySQL, SELECT and COUNT from two différente tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL:

**___Table1**

```
| id | name |
|----|------|
| 98 | Fred |
```

**___Table2**

```
| link | amount |
|------|--------|
|   98 | 100.00 |
|   98 |  50.00 |
```

How can I `SELECT` all the items from ___Table1 and `SUM` datas from the ___Table2.

The desired output should be:

- Fred = 150.00

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT 
SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount FROM ___Table2 WHERE ___Table2.link = ___Table1.id,
(SELECT * FROM ___Estimates ORDER BY EST_Id DESC)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Great that you shared what you tried.  It's also helpful to tell us what the result was.  In this case syntax error.  Here is the reference documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html and in your case your are just looking for "SELECT  select_expr [, select_expr]  ... [FROM table_references  [GROUP BY {col_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
    t1.id AS id,
    t1.name as name,
    IFNULL ( SUM( t2.amount ), 0 ) AS account 
FROM
    ___Table2 t2
    RIGHT JOIN ___Table1 t1 ON t2.link = t1.id 
GROUP BY
    t2.link
```

Comment: This query is illegal because the nonaggregated `t1.name` column in the select list does not appear in the [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: You are right！Does this work：group by t1.id, t1.name

Comment: Also, using a `LEFT JOIN` is meaningless, unlike a `RIGHT JOIN`. Add an entry (99, 'John') to `Table1` and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could group by name instead but you didn't say if it was unique.  If you just need a single user then add a where clause to select that user:

```
select name, sum(amount) as 'sum'
from ___Table1
join ___Table2 on ___Table1.id = ___Table2.link
group by ___Table1.id
```

Those table names are awful (you can't tell how many underscores by just looking at it), also it's a good idea to use the same name for the primary and foreign key (_id is the often used standard).

Comment: No. I need to loop over the ___Table1 and get the sum of the item in ___Table2 that have the same id/link.